# javascript \uff0E string parsing

Tags: javascript

I have a MongoDB collection with documents that contain full periods ie `"\uff0E"`

When I get these documents from Mongo into JavaScript, I get the lovely

```
http://foo．bar．com/baz/
```

What would be the proper way to parse this string to get back this:

```
http://foo.bar.com/baz/
```

Thanks!

Comment: Partially Solved, `url = key.replace("\uff0E", "X");` works... how would i do this for everything in the string...

Comment: fixed: `url = key.replace(/\uff0E/g, ".");`

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var key in urlObject) {
    url = key.replace(/\uff0E/g, ".");
    console.log (url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I had to use dot `.` in the key. MongoDB doesn't support `$` and `.` characters in the key. 
A pre-processor use to convert the keys to Unicode format. U+FF04 (i.e. “＄”) and U+FF0E (i.e. “．”)
Sometimes extra \ gets added to \uff0E, In that case

```
url = key.toLowerCase().replace(/\\uff0e/g, ".");
```

works well